# Pass and Get a php url param without a page reload using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i'm developing a website that i preferred to make the web page (header,nav) static. Only the page content in a particular div gets refreshed according to any page link clicked, using jquery.

Heres the working code

```
$("#nav_page_i").on("click", function () {
$("#load_here").load("addproduct.php");
});
```

(#nav_page_i) is the id for the href and (#load_here) is the div the addproduct.php page content is loaded into.

But is it possible that i pass and get php url params with this method without an actual page reload, as is needed to complete my site.

can i pass php params like this

```
$("#load_here").load("addproduct.php?param1=<?php echo $id?>&param2=<?php echo $id2?>")
```

Comment: Check out ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you can pass params that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
$("#load_here").load("addproduct.php?param1=1&param2=2");
```

in PHP:

```
<?php
   $param1 = $_GET['param1']; // 1
   $param2 = $_GET['param2']; // 2
?>
```

Comment: the values i need to pass in each params are php. how can i do that and get it using php $_GET[]?

Comment: you need to give more code, I don't understand then

Answer (score 1):

You can use php parameters in jquery or javascript like this ,

```
<?php
        $parameter1 = $_GET['foo']; // GET , POST , REQUEST what ever you want
        $parameter2 = $_GET['foo']; 
?>


$("#load_here").load("addproduct.php?parameter1=<?php echo $parameter1; ?>&parameter2=<?php echo $parameter2; ?>");
```

**Please let me know if i understand question in wrong manner.**